# Issue with centering the elements from html begin form in row

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

I have a begin form with input elements and text label. For some reason I cannot center the form in the middle of row. I tried text-align center and it centers only the text not buttons or input fields.

or I tried to apply separate css styles on each element but it is messing around the form.

What is wrong with it?

```
  <section class="my-posted-jobs">

  <div class="row">



   <div class="col-md-6" </div>

     <div class="specific-job col-md-6">
        <div class="row test">


<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h1>Edit Post</h1>

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.JobPostId)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Headline, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Headline, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Headline, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AboutJob, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AboutJob, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AboutJob, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobCity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobCity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobCity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobPostCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobPostCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobPostCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

        </div>
    </div>
</div>





     </section>
```

Comment: You can do this using bootstrap grid https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/grid/  also consider column offset

Comment: Are you using two columns?

Comment: @Tico yes, I use 2 col-md-6

Comment: There is an unclosed div tag `<div class="col-md-6" </div>`

Comment: @VDWWD I ensured that everything is closed, maybe I missed one when I copy pasted my code here :)